# How do I edit fixed text inside span with Jquery

Tags: jquery

This is my span html

```
<span class="k-pager-info k-label">1 - 20 of 91 items</span>
```

I want to Rename items to records using Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('span').text(function(){
    return this.innerText.replace('items','records');
});
```

**Snippet,**

```js
$('span').text(function(){
  return this.innerText.replace('items','records');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="k-pager-info k-label">1 - 20 of 91 items</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".k-label").html('21 - 40 of 91 items');
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a `.text` function that can be used for this. The callback has the text passed along, and in my example, I replace the necessary part of the string and then returned it so that the UI can be updated by jQuery with the new text.

```js
$("span.k-pager-info").text(function(index, text) {
  return text.replace("items", "records");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="k-pager-info k-label">1 - 20 of 91 items</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `split` and `replace` you can get your result.

```js
var oldVal = $('.k-label').text();
var repItem = oldVal.split(' ').pop(-1);
var result =oldVal.replace(repItem,'records')
console.log(result);
$('.k-label').text(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="k-pager-info k-label">1 - 20 of 91 items</span>
```